# iOS ViewController Not Dismissing After UnityAds Video View

Tags: ios, objective-c, unityads

I'm attempting to create a new View Controller for displaying rewarded videos to users using either UnityAds and Vungle (depending on which is available).

After a Vungle video view, the `VungleSDKDelegate` will call `vungleSDKwillCloseAdWithViewInfo` which I have implemented as such:

```
- (void)vungleSDKwillCloseAdWithViewInfo:(NSDictionary *)viewInfo willPresentProductSheet:(BOOL)willPresentProductSheet {
    NSLog(@"vungleSDKwillCloseAdWithViewInfo");

    [self finishVideoView];
}
```

And `finishVideoView` as:

```
- (void) finishVideoView {
    NSLog(@"finishVideoView");
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

This works great, when it's done, the view controller is dismissed and the app resumes. However, when I attempt to do this method in Unity's `UnityAdsDelegate`'s method `unityAdsDidFinish`, the view controller just hangs out there and never dismisses.

```
- (void)unityAdsDidFinish:(NSString *)placementId withFinishState:(UnityAdsFinishState)state{
    NSLog(@"unityAdsDidFinish");

    [self finishVideoView];
}
```

Any ideas why? It seems that the `unityAdsDidFinish` callback happens right after I hit the x at the top of the finished video.

I thought it might be a timing issue so I also tried doing:
`[self performSelector:@selector(finishVideoView) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];`

But that does not seem to help either.

Comment: have you checked if the `unityAdsDidFinish:withFinishState:` is invoked on the main queue ?

Comment: I have not. What's the best way to do that?

Comment: a breakpoint in `unityAdsDidFinish:withFinishState:` & looking at the queue name mentioned in the debug navigator or add `NSLog(@"is on main queue: %@", @([NSThread isMainThread]));`

Comment: Looks like it's on the main thread.

Comment: damn! can you check if the `self` object in `unityAdsDidFinish:` is _actually_ the view controller you want to dismiss, adding a `NSLog(@"self object class: %@", [self class])`. Is the class logged the view controller to be dismissed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up decided to avoid waiting on the delegate methods and instead implementing `finishVideoView` in my ViewController's `viewWillAppear` method. It seems to work now - whenever my view controller appears again, it checks the BOOL to see if a video has played, if so, it finishes the controller.